# asp.net mvc linq clearification database call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

```
   var Dic = _db.Dictionaries.Single(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id);
   var DicRef = Dic.DictionaryRefs.Where(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id);
```

The second one will make a database call or will it based on Dic?

Answer (score 0):

That depends. You can configure your DataContext to do lazy loading (make a database call when needed) or eager loading (load everything at once). LINQ to SQL uses lazy loading (or deferred loading) by default:

```
using (YourDataContext _db = new YourDataContext())
{
    // This will no load any child object/collection. They are requested
    // when needed.
    var Dic = _db.Dictionaries.Single(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id);

    // Now the DictionaryRefs get loaded from the database
    var DicRef = Dic.DictionaryRefs.Where(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id).ToList();

    // Now the DisplayModes get loaded from the database
    var DicDisplay = Dic.DisplayModes.Where(m => m.DisplayID = displayId).ToList();
}
```

You can either turn lazy loading off completely:

```
using (YourDataContext _db = new YourDataContext())
{
    _db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

    // This will load the DictionaryRefs child collection
    // (and any other child object/collection of Dictionary) as well
    var Dic = _db.Dictionaries.Single(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id);

    // No call to the database is needed. DictionaryRefs are already loaded
    var DicRef = Dic.DictionaryRefs.Where(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id).ToList();

    // No call to the database is needed. DisplayModes are already loaded
    var DicDisplay = Dic.DisplayModes.Where(m => m.DisplayID = displayId).ToList();
}
```

Or, you can leave lazy loading on and tell your DataContext to eagerly load only *some* relations:

```
using (YourDataContext context = new YourDataContext())
{
    DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
    options.LoadWith<Dictionary>(d => d.DictionaryRefs);

    context.LoadOptions = options;

    // This will load the DictionaryRefs child collection as well,
    // but other child objects/collection will not me loaded
    var Dic = _db.Dictionaries.Single(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id);

    // No call to the database is needed. DictionaryRefs are already loaded
    var DicRef = Dic.DictionaryRefs.Where(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id).ToList();

    // Now the DisplayModes get loaded from the database
    var DicDisplay = Dic.DisplayModes.Where(m => m.DisplayID = displayId).ToList();
}
```

Using these options, you can control how related objects are loaded and accessed. Also note that I requested every child collection with the `ToList()` method. That's because LINQ to SQL only makes a call to the database when a query actually needs to be accessed.

For example:

```
using (YourDataContext _db = new YourDataContext())
{
    var comments = _db.Comments.Where(c => c.PostID = 5);

    // At this point, no call has been made to the database yet.

    // Now the database is called, because you want to use the comments
    foreach(var comment in comments)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add aggregate to force it to run.

```
var DicRef = Dic.DictionaryRefs.Where(m => m.int_DictionaryId == id).ToList();
```